# 社内環境におけるmavenのプロキシ認証エラーについて

Tags: java, windows, maven

初めて質問させていただきます。よろしくお願いいたします。

掲題の問題が起きており、アドバイスを頂きたく存じます。

現在、社内での開発環境*としてWindows7上にmavenを導入しようとしております。
注：社内開発環境について
-OS: Windows7 SP1
-maven version: Apache Maven 3.3.9
-Java version: 1.8.0_60
-その他: 社内プロキシ（ユーザアカウント認証あり）を介して、インターネットに接続可能

mavenをWindows7に導入し、以下のコマンドでサンプルプロジェクトの作成を試みた所、エラーメッセージが出力されます。

○投入コマンド（コマンドプロンプト）

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=sample
```

○エラー時ログ（コマンドプロンプト上表示された内容抜粋）

```
…
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 via [社内プロキシサーバ名]:[プロキシ用ポート] with username=[社内プロキシアカウント名], password=***
…（省略）
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required" from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='[社内プロキシサーバ名]', userName='null', port=[プロキシ用ポート], type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required" from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml with proxyInfo ProxyInfo{host='[社内プロキシサーバ名]', userName='null', port=[プロキシ用ポート], type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}

（↑上記のような407エラーが、大量に発生。）
```

プロキシの設定については、`%UserProfile%\.m2\settings.xml`に以下の通り設定しています。

○settings.xml設定内容

```
<settings>
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy-http</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>[社内プロキシサーバ名]</host>
      <port>[プロキシ用ポート]</port>
      <username>[社内プロキシアカウント名]</username>
      <password>[社内プロキシパスワード]</password>
    </proxy>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy-https</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>[社内プロキシサーバ名]</host>
      <port>[プロキシ用ポート]</port>
      <username>[社内プロキシアカウント名]</username>
      <password>[社内プロキシパスワード]</password>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
</settings>
```

コマンドプロント表示のログにある[DEBUG]行の表示を見る限り、settings.xmlからプロキシサーバ名やプロキシアカウントは取得できているようですが、エラー行では、`ProxyInfo{host='[社内プロキシサーバ名]', userName='null', port=[プロキシ用ポート], type='http', nonProxyHosts='null'}`となっており、userNameはnullとなってしまっているように見受けられます。

色々と過去事例等調べておりますが、解決まで至っている過去事例もなかったため、本サイトにて質問させていただいております。
社内環境での作業であり、プロキシサーバの設定等は確認することが難しいです。

解決策について、ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご助言いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 同バージョンのmavenで試してみたのですが、そもそも`archetype:create`自体がエラーになりますね(確かかなり前から[deprecatedになっていた](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html)はず)。代わりに[`archetype:generate`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html)を指定しても、やはり同じエラーになるのでしょうか。

Comment: ＞yukihaneさま
確認してみたところ、状況は変わりないようです。
また、上記エラーログについて誤った部分があったので、本文差し替えます。
（ただし、407のエラーコードリターン状況に変わりはありません。）

Answer (score 1):

mavenのインストールディレクトリにあるconf/setting.xmlを編集したら結果はどうなりますか？

それでうまくいくのであればglobal設定が先に効いていると思われます。
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

環境変数M2_HOMEの値を確認してみて下さい

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
conf以下を編集してみても、状況に変化はありませんでした。
.m2以下のsettings.xmlを削除し、試してみましたが同様の状態です。(よって、globalの設定も読めている様子)

Answer (score 1):

ログを拝見したところ、通常のmavenを使っただけでは出力されないはずの Eclise aether(エーテル)のログが出ています。
http://www.eclipse.org/aether/

このエーテルを使ってmavenを実行している環境ではないでしょうか。

なお、お使いのPCの環境変数(PATH)を確認するのも大事ですが、コマンドで実行している

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=sample
```

にて実行されている、sampleプロジェクト内にあるpom.xmlの中にプロクシの設定が書かれている、またはプロファイルを指定していて、profile.xmlを読み込んでいてプロクシの設定を書き換えている疑いがあります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！週末で社内環境にアクセスできないため、週明けにいただいた内容について確認してみたいと思います。